# How to enforce future on IObservable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I constantly hit this problem when building my workflow so here is the question. Entire problem is about time.

When it does not matter -- for example when I connect `IObservable` to some GUI element, it is all fine. GUI element simply is updated as it gets new data, that's all I care about.

But there is another category (with two subcategories) -- no-past data (current+future, and future only). I would like to use such `IObservable` (or use `Subscribe` in such way) that I would get only future data.

When you have some steering logic it is crucial to make a difference, trivial example -- I subscribe to earthquake indicator and if the value reaches the threshold I will start alarm. Now, if my observable would send me old data I would start false alarm. That's bad :-).

So is there a way to either limit `IObservable` to future observable, or execute `Subscribe` in such limiting way? So far I rely on `Subject`s instead because their behavior is well defined when it comes to time.

*To sum this up -- I would like to have 3 types in total: for any time (here there is `IObservable` already), for current+future data and the third -- future data only.*

**Update:** see below for  Enigmativity comments -- let's say I have producer with given semantics, for example current+future (say `BehaviorSubject`). Now, I can pass further `BehaviorSubject` or I could pass `IObservable` -- but in the latter case I have to live with belief everyone pass `IObservable` with desired semantics, because I have no chance to enforce it (at least I don't see how) even in runtime.

Comment: You are looking for a hot observable. Take a look at Lee Campbell's IntroToRx chapter about Hot and Cold observables. http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html

Comment: @supertopi, thank you but this is not a difference here -- hot/cold tells you if the "processing" is done even if unobserved (if I am not mistaken). I am asking about time, I would like to get (a) any data, (b) current and future data, (c) only future data. Even this tells you this is something different, because you have here 3 categories, not 2.

Comment: Ok, I got it.. your question has a very high emphasis on getting only future data if not read very carefully :) So you should be able to support all three temporal categories?

Comment: @supertopi, well, "should" -- I now wonder how to do it. I hope there is some way, because otherwise I would have to add my own wrappers, ouch :-).

Comment: Let's say you want to play baseball and you want to be the batter, so you have to get someone else to pitch. Now the pitcher may pitch a curve ball or a fast ball, and you, as the batter, can't change the ball in flight from a fast ball to a curve ball - you are stuck with what the pitcher pitches. Now if you only want fast balls then get a pitcher who pitches only fast balls. Now if you only want curve balls then get a pitcher who pitches only curve balls. The same with Rx. You have all the control in the world if you're pitching.

Comment: @Enigmativity, could you please provide tiny example? You are pitcher (consumer of `IObservable`) and you want to get "current+future" semantics. I pass to you `IObservable` with "future only" semantics. How do you get the current?

Comment: @astrowalker - I was really trying to make the point that the consumer of the observable cannot change the semantics. You must ensure the producer provides the correct semantics.

Comment: @Enigmativity, of course, but my point is, that so far I didn't find anything else than `IObservable` and I don't want to use it as vehicle to pass time semantics, because it is too fragile. So I think it is better to write wrappers like `IFutureObservable`.

Comment: @astrowalker - No, it's not better. Don't write `IFutureObservable`. That's a mistake. Construct your observable to suit your needs.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I think it is safe to say we are walking in the loop. You tell me not to write a wrapper, but construct observable that suits my needs. I can do it, but I cannot enforce semantics on it. So I would have to rely on "trust" or there need to be a wrapper (or ready to use interface), but then I should not write a wrapper :-).

Comment: @astrowalker - We're not walking in a loop. I'm consistently telling you not to write wrappers. You keep going back there. The bottom-line is that you can enforce whatever semantics you desire, but there is no way to tell the semantics by looking at the type. This is no different than `XDocument`, for example, by looking at the type you can't tell the content. When coding we very often use the name of the variable to indicate the behaviour. That's standard. Something like `IObservable currentPlusFuture` or `IObservable futureOnly`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, having a function like `void consumer(IObservable<T> futureOnly)` is too fragile (for me). Because it is very error prone to errors. Sooner or later somebody forget about the name and pass "current+future" observable there.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the responsibility of producing/handling past data on the subscriber. It should be a feature of the producer. i.e. If you gui doesnt want to get the last (past) value then it shouldn't subscribe to a sequence with replay/behaviour semantics.

Instead the sequence should just yield new values. If other parts of the gui want o get padt data then they would subscribe to a different sequence. Now this sequence might be simply an eagerly subcribed (connected) Replay over the same sequence or the values maybe provided by a different backend query.

The Reactive Trader example project sgows a gui that deals with both of these concerns

Comment: "then it shouldn't subscribe to a sequence with replay/behaviour semantics", well, I agree, but `IObservable` does not expose **any** semantics. What interfaces I am missing -- are there any `IFutureObservable`? In other words how use interfaces (not concrete classes) with desired semantics? I didn't find them so far.

Comment: @astrowalker - Lee's right. You are meant to construct the observable with the right semantics and not make the observer do anything special.

Comment: @Enigmativity, ah, you mean I should built a class and interface with appropriate names and behavior and simply use them, because there is nothing ready to use within RX, correct? I am doing this already, I asked to find out if I don't miss something :-).

Comment: Alot of people have struggled with this. I have been on teams that created marker interfaces over IObservable. However this did not prove fruitful. Instead, naming of methods to express behaviour and cardinality became the standard

Comment: @astrowalker - "you mean I should built a class and interface with appropriate names and behavior and simply use them" - No, absolutely not. You should **not** build any classes and interfaces in any way that are to augment Rx. Rx is beautiful as is. You need to use the existing operators to build queries that behave in the way that you want, and then just consume them. You should follow Lee's advice. He knows what he is talking about.

Comment: @Enigmativity, so you think about adding proxy/cache in the middle so I could get desired behavior? Hmm, let's say there is a function `foo(IObservable<int> data)`. How do I use existing operators in such way that I would get from it "present+future" semantics? I dare to say it is impossible because `IObservable` is too vague.

Comment: @astrowalker - I didn't say anything about a "proxy/cache". You need to construct `IObservable<int> data` to get the desired behaviour that you want. You need to think with a function programming mindset - not OOP.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I still don't see it, sorry. See my updated post (above), in short if your target is `IObservable` you just lost time semantics.

Comment: You could choose to see it like that. But you could say the samw with an Ienumerable off a queue. Is it a competing consumer? Last value cache? Not everything can be enforced in the type system

Comment: @enigmativity cant contact you any other way, but it would be great if you presented at RxDevCon.com

Comment: @LeeCampbell - You can email me via james at my SO id dot com.